# Запуск выполнения одного скрипта из другого

Tags: php

Есть php-скрипт, который запускается кроном каждую минуту.
Этот скрипт проверяет некоторые условия и запускает другие скрипты (например, инклудом).
Безусловно "родительский" скрипт не перейдёт к проверке и запуску второго дочернего скрипта, пока не выполнится первый.
Вопрос: каким образом из php можно запустить скрипт и продолжить выполнение текущего?
Получается что-то вроде собственного небольшого "задачника": системный крон запускает один скрипт каждую минуту, а он уже запускает следующие, в случае выполнения некоторых условий (в том числе по времени).

Comment: попробуйте system("php newscript.php &"); правда так вы не узнаете когда он закончится, так что думаю более првильно будет покопать в сторону fork и exec

Comment: Разве system не ждёт выполнение команды, прежде чем продолжить выполнение текущего скрипта? Мне так-то не надо знать, когда он закончился, закончился и чёрт с ним. Главное чтобы после запуска родительский скрипт сразу продолжил работу, а не ждал. Вот насчёт fork да, слышал, но как-то подробно-понятных примеров не нашёл:) Есть интересные ссылки по теме?:) Буду благодарен:)

Comment: system конечно должен ждать. но `&` в конце командной строки отправляет задачу в фоновое выполнение

Comment: Да, и в случае если родительский скрипт остановить - команда продолжит выполняться. А необходимо чтобы родительский скрипт запустил дочерний скрипт и сразу перешёл к запуску следующего дочернего.

Comment: Ну так `&` именно это и сделает. Если родитеский скрипт может завершмтся раньше то запускать лучше `nohup php scritp.php &` что бы дочерний процес продолжил работать и после завершения родительского

Comment: Очень любопытно, зачем вам параллельно выполнять несколько скриптов?

Comment: Mike, либо вы ошибаетесь, либо у меня была какая-то ошибка, ибо если в скрипте прописать два system, даже с & - то второй не начнёт выполняться, пока не закончится первый.

Comment: tutankhamun, в моём посте я дал ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать pcntl_fork .
Эта функция возвращает pid дочернего процесса в родительский и 0 - в дочерний , то есть, если вы напишете if , в этой точке одна ветка пойдет в родительском процессе, а другая в дочернем. Так можно запустить дочерний процесс, где будет вызываться нужный вам "другой" скрипт, в то время как в родительском процессе можно продолжить работу основного скрипта. Только, насколько я помню, в модуле apache эта функция работать не будет

Comment: Спасибо. Я изучал информацию по pcntl_fork до того, как написал сей пост, но почему-то боялся попробовать его. Решение, как оказалось, заняло, по сути, 20 символов:)